# Multiple Cascading Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I need to be able select multiple vehicles on a web page using JQuery.
Selecting the Make in the first dropdown populates the second dropdown with the Models for that Make.

> ddlMake1 should populate ddlModel1
>   ddlMake2 should populate ddlModel2
>   ddlMake3 should populate ddlModel3

Initially populating the dropdowns works fine, and if I only add one set, it works just fine.  When I add a second or third set, it populates all sets properly, but if I select any of the makes, it populates the Models in the last set.

> selecting ddlMake1/2/3 populates ddlModel3

I would like he model to be 'connected' to it's make.  Where am I going wrong?

```
<body>
<select id="ddlMake1"></select><select id="ddlModel1"></select><br />
<select id="ddlMake2"></select><select id="ddlModel2"></select><br />
<select id="ddlMake3"></select><select id="ddlModel3"></select>
</body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        loadDropdownData('ddlMake1', 'ddlModel1');
        loadDropdownData('ddlMake2', 'ddlModel2');
        loadDropdownData('ddlMake3', 'ddlModel3');
    });
</script>

function loadDropdownData(make, model) {
var data = {
    'Acura': { 'CSX': [], 'EL': [], 'ILX': []}, 
    'Audi': { 'A4': [], 'A5': [], 'A6': []}, 
    'BMW': { '1 Series': [], '2 Series': [], '3 Series':[]}
};


$a = $("#" + make);
$b = $("#" + model);

$a.html('');

for (var prop in data) {
    var first = prop;
    $a.append($("<option>").attr("value", first).text(first));
}

$a.change(function () {
    var firstkey = $(this).val();
    $b.html('');
    for (var prop in data[firstkey]) {
        var second = prop;
        $b.append($("<option>").attr("value", second).text(second));
    }

}).change();
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your $b variable was being declared outside of the scope of your function. By adding var you create the variable new every time the function is called.

http://jsfiddle.net/35yyv/1/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        loadDropdownData('ddlMake1', 'ddlModel1');
        loadDropdownData('ddlMake2', 'ddlModel2');
        loadDropdownData('ddlMake3', 'ddlModel3');
    });

function loadDropdownData(make, model) {
var data = {
    'Acura': { 'CSX': [], 'EL': [], 'ILX': []}, 
    'Audi': { 'A4': [], 'A5': [], 'A6': []}, 
    'BMW': { '1 Series': [], '2 Series': [], '3 Series':[]}
};

var $a = $("#" + make);
var $b = $("#" + model);


$a.html('');

for (var prop in data) {
    var first = prop;
    $a.append($("<option>").attr("value", first).text(first));
}

$a.change(function () {

    var firstkey = $(this).val();
    $b.html('');
    for (var prop in data[firstkey]) {
        var second = prop;
        $b.append($("<option>").attr("value", second).text(second));
    }

}).change();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is scope of variables, use this:

```
var $a = $("#" + make);
var $b = $("#" + model);
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks.  If I could mark 2 as answer I would.